# Notepad++ replace with single character exception?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am trying to put together a regex for the "Find in Files" find and replace feature of Notepad++.

I need to find any occurrence of: `href="whatever"` and prepend the url with `/data/` so that it becomes: `href="/data/whatever"`

However, I need to exclude any such find that already contains an initial slash, i.e.: `href="/whatever"` needs to be skipped.

It seems this should be easy as regex goes and I have studied many examples and have come to what I think should work!  But it's not working.  Can someone tell me where this is going wrong?

```
Find: href="([^/]*)"
Replace: href="/data/\1"
```

Thanks for any help - it is frustrating when you don't do this every day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this regex replacement:

```
Find: href="([^/][^"]+)"
Replace: href="/data/\1"
```

In the regex:

```
href="([^/][^"]+)"
        \     \ skips to the end of the "s, effectively landing on "
         \ asserts that the first character is not /
```

Here is a [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/kG0uE1/2).

Comment: Ahh of course the escape... and I see now the way to get to the end of the url.  Not only does this answer my question but helped me springboard on some deeper regex's I was working out - Thanks much!

Comment: There're no needs to escape the slash.